# Why didn't the characters wake up when the van went off the bridge in Inception?

Tags: inception

In one of the early scenes it shows Cobb being pushed backwards off a chair to be woken up out of the dream.

Considering the van crashing through a barrier and falling through the air (never mind the chase leading up to this) would produce a similar affect as falling off a chair, why did this not wake any of the characters up?

Comment: ... in particular Arthur, who doesn't go any deeper.  Actually this question has been asked before.